# When to stop pumping up balloons?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Yesterday I acted as a volunteer in a psychology/neurology experiment where one of the trials consisted of playing a computer game in which you had to click the mouse to pump up a balloon. For each click you gained one unit of money, but if you clicked too many times, the balloon would pop and you got nothing; the idea was to stop at some moment and collect the money, ideally just before it popped (maximizing the gain). The catch was that all balloons (you had twenty balloons to make money off) were different as to when they would pop. I was wondering what the optimal strategy might be.

> Assuming that the balloons pop according to a random variable $X$ with a Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and width $\sigma$, how many times should one click the mouse to maximize profits?

I figured we should use the normal CDF for finding the probability $P(k)$ of the balloon popping after $k$ clicks, i.e. $$P(k)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^k e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$$

I'm a bit wary of using $0$ as the lower limit, instead of $-\infty$, but since I start at $0$ clicks it seemed to make more sense.

After $k$ clicks, we have gained either $k$ money, with probability $1-P(k)$, or $0$ money, with probability $P(k)$. Therefore, I'm guessing the expectation value of the profit $f(k)$ should be $$\langle f(k) \rangle=\frac{k(1-P(k))+0\cdot P(k)}{2}=\frac{k}{2}(1-P(k))$$

But now (assuming this is correct, which it probably isn't, since I don't have any experience whatsoever with random variables), I don't know how to maximize this function, since it is discrete. Were it continuous, I'd simply differentiate, set equal to $0$ and solve for $k$, and this yields $$P(k)+kP'(k)=1$$ which I don't know how to solve either.

I threw a Monte-Carlo after it and got this:

[image]

The lower $\sigma$ gets, the closer the CDF gets to a step-function, so it makes sense that the slope nears $1$ (meaning that you should stop only right before you reach $\mu$) in the limits $\sigma \to 0$. In general, it seems one should stop a little after $\mu-\sigma$, but not much.

---

How do I solve this analytically?
If not analytically (this might be hard since the integral of a Gaussian can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions) then numerically? What would an algorithm be?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1868649/21820 for a generalized question that I just asked (not knowing that you had asked this earlier, as pointed out by *joriki*). We did the same analysis for a known distribution. =)